# Eclipse plugin for LESS: How to hide errors of CSS frameworks?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, less

I just installed Eclipse plugin for LESS (http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-less.fr.html).

I followed the install instructions there. Now I am able to open an LESS file with the LESS editor coming with the plugin.

However, I now see many LESS errors reported about CSS frameworks such bootstrap because of installing this plugin. How can I hide these errors? The instructions there seems not helpful.

Here is the structure of my folders.

webapp

---less/styles.less

---lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.less

Thanks for any input!

Comment: how about asking the plugin's author instead?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just did it. Hope other folks with experience in this tool can help me too. If I hear anything from the author, I will post it here.

Answer (score 2):

I got reply from the code author. Here it goes:

Hello,

Youu can go in the project properties, selection Validation and then 
LESS.  Then you can disable some type of errors.

Hope this helps,

--
Vincent